# How to fill cell with 50% intensity of an hexadecimal color using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, colors, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl with python 3.10 to create a xls file from a dataBase.
I extract an hexadacimal color from this dataBase and I want to fill cells with this color but only with 50% intensity. Currently, i have this :

```
import sqlite3, openpyxl

def getRouteColor(route):
    cursor.execute('''SELECT route_color
                       FROM routes
                       WHERE route_short_name = "{}"'''.format(route))
    return cursor.fetchall()[0][0]

[...]
color = getRouteColor(route) #hexadecimal

for column in sheet.columns: 
  for cell in column:
        if not cell.row % 2:
             cell.fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(patternType = 'solid', fgColor = color)
```

I've try to use different patternType to lower intensity but it wasn't conclusive because I don't want lines or dots.
Do you have any ideas of how to get a 50% intensity (using openpyxl, or other way like get a 50% intensity hexadecimal code from the 100% intensity hexadecimal code) ?

Comment: Hi @Eijaf - what do you mean by intensity? Are you trying to make the color lighter? Are you trying to make the cell more transparent? In terms of RGB, what are you expecting to be reduced by 50%?

Comment: Thanks. In term of RGB I was looking for an alpha of 0.5. That's in fact the way I have solve my problem for the moment : convert my hex color to RGB, apply  : alpha * (RGB) + (1 - alpha) * backgroundColor, and then convert back to hex. It seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do it :

I convert my hexadecimal color to RGB color and apply an alpha of 0.5 to it. Then, I convert it back to hexadecimal :

```
def color50(color): #color : hexadecimal 'XXXXXX'
   rgb = tuple(int(color[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))
   rgb50 = []
   for i in rgb : 
      rgb50.append(int(0.5 * i + (1 - 0.5) * 255))
   return '{:X}{:X}{:X}'.format(rgb50[0], rgb50[1], rgb50[2])
```

If you have a better way to do it I'm still interested