# Openpyxl cell fill color include alpha value

Tags: openpyxl

I have a codeblock using PatternFill:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filename)
if f'Parameter 1' in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb['Parameter 1']
else:
    ws = wb.create_sheet(f'Parameter 1', 0)
my_fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='1A801AC3', bgColor='1A801AC3')
ws.cell(row=32, column=8, value='Hello').fill = my_fill
```

I expect to fill my cell with almost transparent color, but I have solid fill with color(801AC3) and no transparency at all, as if I do not pass any alpha in aRGB.

Comment: The alpha value does nothing. Perhaps the OOXML specs require an aRGB value but doesn't make any difference what its set to. The Openpyxl  code will prefix '00' to the value if you specify just the RGB values to make it aRGB. '00' would make the fill color fully transparent if it had an affect.

Comment: You could consider doing something like the workaround @Eijaf made in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72956927/13664137)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue modifiying @Eijaf's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72956927/13664137) ,
where alpha is in percentage from 0 to 1

```
def color_alpha(color, alpha):
    rgb = tuple(int(color[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))
    rgb_alpha = []
    for i in rgb : 
        rgb_alpha.append(int(alpha * i + (1 - alpha) * 255))
    return '{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(rgb_alpha[0], rgb_alpha[1], rgb_alpha[2])
```